# Unable to change session variables in zend .. is the approach wrong?

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework

Here are the steps that i have followed till now :

Firstly i have initialized the namespace for my session

```
$guest_events = new Zend_Session_Namespace('guest_events');
```

then added an array to the session

```
$guest_events-> events = array();
```

then i added some events to the array.

which looks like :

```
Array
(
    [amount_0] => 1
    [event_id_0] => 69
    [event_title_0] => Sunday Collection
    [amount_1] => 11
    [event_id_1] => 78
    [event_title_1] => Test event

)
```

Now in my another controller when i try to implement edit amount functionality through ajax :

```
$event_id = $this-> getRequest()-> getParam('event_id');
        $edit_amount = $this-> getRequest()-> getParam('edit_amount');
        $event_title = $this-> getRequest() -> getParam('event_title');
$guest_events = new Zend_Session_Namespace('guest_events');
$event_array = $guest_events-> events;
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i ++)
        {
          if (array_key_exists('event_id_'.$i, $event_array))
          {     

                if ($event_array['event_id_'.$i]==$event_id && $event_array['event_title_'.$i]==$event_title)
                {   
                     // unset the amount and replace with new one 
                    unset($guest_events-> events-> amount_0);
                    $guest_events-> events-> amount_0 = $edit_amount;
                }
          }
        }
```

i have tried everything but the session variables remain unchanged .. can anyone tell why ?? :(

Answer (score 1):

If the element `events` is an array in your `Zend_Session_Namespace` object, then you should be setting it like this:

```
$guest_events-> events['amount_0'] = $edit_amount;
```

instead of like:

```
$guest_events-> events-> amount_0 = $edit_amount;
```

Also, since you are in a loop which finds the correct numeric value, I think it should actually be:

```
$guest_events-> events['amount_' . $i] = $edit_amount;
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem .. it isn't going inside the inner if loop .. i.e :

```
if ($event_array['event_id_'.$i]==$event_id && $event_array['event_title_'.$i]==$event_title)
                {   
                     // unset the amount and replace with new one 
                    unset($guest_events-> events-> amount_0);
                    $guest_events-> events-> amount_0 = $edit_amount;
                }
```

still cant figure out why this is happening though :/

Comment: Are you actually sending the original event title via Ajax?  You only enter that block if the transmitted ID and title match what is already in the session.

Comment: yup .. the request is made by ajax and amount is replaced after matching event id and event title

Comment: Then there must be some minor mismatch between the values sent and what is stored in the session since it isn't finding a match for both title and ID in the array.  Next debug step is to look at each comparison one at a time and see why the correct one isn't matching.